# How iOS Photos app Collection view layout works

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to create an app like `iPhone Photos`
the `Photos` App loads all the images in the Collections in small grids, how the collection view cells will be resized as per the images, is there any `library` or `built-in SDK` to do this

I want to display images in my app like in iOS Photos app `collections/years`, is i have to use `UICollectionView` or Any other Object to achieve this

I googled for this, i cannot find any library or hint regarding the `Mosaic` view like `iPhone Photos App`

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use UICollectionView for this task.

Example: Three controllers in navigation stack with different UICollectionViews:

1. Years. Every year's time range has own section.
2. Year. Every month's time range has own section.
3. Month. Every day's time range has own section.

Comment: Can you please suggest any SDK for Mosaic view used in the collectionView in Years